# Running strapply in the absence of tcltk in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a data frame with one column carrying a list variable.  The list variable contains duplicate elements which I want to remove.  The following is the code that I am using:

```
library(gsubfn)

Loading required package: proto
Could not load tcltk.  Will use slower R code instead.

resp$secu <- as.character(lapply(strapply(resp[[7]], "\\w")), unique)
```

I am using R 3.2.0 version on mac.  I tried loading tcltk manually without success:

```
library(tcltk)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’
```

I uninstalled library tcltk and tried re-installing but couldn't:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
```

I could execute the code and R started without any error messages.  But it had taken an hour for a 65k row list to remove the duplicates and the processing yet to complete.  Is there a way to improve the speed of strapply without using tcltk library?

Comment: Did you see this line? `error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org`

Comment: Yes Pascal, I did.  I tried installing XQuartz again got the error message     Warning in install.packages : package 'XQuartz' is not available (for R version 3.2.0)

Comment: XQuartz is a program, not a package, get it from http://xquartz.macosforge.org

Comment: Read gsubfn FAQs #1 and #2: https://code.google.com/p/gsubfn/#FAQs

Comment: Many thanks...I have installed both XQuartz from quartz.macosforge.org and tcltk directly from CRAN again....though I could not see tcltk library in my RStudio package panel, I could execute my strapply code successfully....and it processed the data in less than an minute.